# Try / catch / retry for all database queries in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception

Let's say I have a Laravel app which isn't a classic web site and that this app is running in an unreliable environment. Unreliable in a sense that at any point of time an aspect of the environment may suddenly become unavailable for a short period of time. We can focus on the database server in this here question. And let's say that I want to create an application resilient to these problems where it is more important that the query eventually gets executed than to respond with a fancy error message.

So, I want to implement something like this:

```
for ($numRetries = 0; $numRetries <= MAX_NUM_RETIRES; $numRetries++) {
    try {
        // run the DB CRUD command
    } catch (SomeExceptionsInWhichImInterestedIn $e) {
        sleep(SOME_TIME);
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

The question is... Where? What I don't want to do is to have to surround every DB call with a chunk of code like this, I want it **automatically applied everywhere** in the application. I've been looking at middleware, events, observers, into the Eloquent model class itself, but I'm still not sure how to do it.

Comment: An idea would be to do your unreliable queries in a job with a try catch. Then use your queue worker to set the amount of retries. If the job fails the try catch throws an exception and the job fails. Probably not best practice though. Have you looked into database transactions?

Comment: For the database specifically you can also consider using [transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions). If there is some failure you can roll back.